# Soundex Search with Solr

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, solr, fuzzy-search, sunspot-solr

I have implemented Solr Search and its working good to some extent. I want to implement search similar to IMDB. I have added the phonetic algorithm filter in Solr. It work for some use cases as follow

**Good Use Case**

Query: "Silvertor Stallon"
Result: "Slyvestor Stallone"

Query:  "Angelena Jole"
Result: "Angelina Jolie"

**Bad Use Case**

Query:  Anglina Jolie
Result: [] # Empty Array. While as I mentioned above I have Angelina Jolie in Database.

Can someone please guide me what is the problem or why Solr not finding "Anglina"

Here is my Solr configuration

```
   <fieldType name="text" class="solr.TextField" omitNorms="false">
      <analyzer>
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.StandardFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="1" maxGramSize="20" side="front"/>
        <filter class="solr.PhoneticFilterFactory" encoder="DoubleMetaphone" inject="true"/>
      </analyzer>
    </fieldType>
```

**More Details:**

Its a Rails project and i have used Sunspot for interaction with Solr.

Looking forward a great help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should really be using Solr Admin UI's Analyze screen. There, you can choose your field, put your source text and your search text and see what happens and whether they match.

In your specific case, I suspect that you cannot combine EdgeNGramFilterFactory and PhoneticFilterFactory. You will get random prefixes of text and *then* you try to derive phonetic information. Also, EdgeNGramFilterFactory is usually on the indexing side only and you see to be using the same definition for both indexing and query time.